# Firebase deploy SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: firebase, node-modules, shopify-app

I'm trying to deploy Shopify nodejs app to firebase. The following node_module causes the problem:

"@shopify/shopify-express": "^1.0.0-alpha.7",

and getting the following error:

```
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/node_modules/@shopify/shopify-express/routes/index.js:19);
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@shopify/shopify-express/index.js:2:22)


Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Is there any chance to deploy with this module? firebase serve is working fine.

Comment: It looks like there is a syntax error in that module.  Try filing a bug with shopify.

Comment: @DougStevenson, yeah I also thought about it but locally it's working fine.